# WCF REST service doesn't work on an IIS6 virtual server

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, iis-6

Problem is I have a very simple WCF REST service, which I wrote starting from the WCF Service application template.

I have one method, one class set up like this

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class MainService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{ricCode}")]
    public IdentifierInfo GetByRicCode(string ricCode)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

When ran from my machine I have no problems it works fine (typical).
My problem is that when I publish this to a website on IIS6 (set up for anonymous access and on a virtual server) all I get from the above method is a 400 - invalid request.

When I changed the method as a test to this

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
    public string GetByRicCode()
    {
         return "foo";
    }
```

and ran in on the IIS6 server it worked fine.
Maybe I set up the virtual server wrong on IIS... any ideas please?

Comment: Can you enable tracing and find out what error you get for the 400 response?

Comment: Never mind I figured out the problem, it was throwing an exception due to nested web.configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, it was throwing an exception due to nested web.configs
How annoying.